# Real Analysis Open sets & Open Balls

Tags: real-analysis

I very well know that every open ball is an open set. and that every open set need not be an open ball. But illustrate me some counter example.

Comment: A counter example on what? An open set that is not a ball?

Comment: If I get your question, then just look what is the union of 2 open balls with no intersection. And in general open balls are some special cases of open sets.

Comment: Take, for example, the subset $\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : |x|<1,|y|<1\}$. It's the interior of the square of side size 2, centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's possible to prove that this set is open and it is obviously not a ball.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counterexample.

Consider the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers.  Let $B(0, 2)$ represent the ball of radius $2$ around $0$, i.e, the interval $(0-2, 0+2) = (-2,2)$.

Now let $B(5,2)$ represent the ball of radius $2$ around $5$, i.e., the interval $(5-2, 5+2) = (3,7)$.

The union of these two balls, $B(0,2) \cup B(5,2)$, is open, but it is not itself a ball because every open ball in $\Bbb R$ can be expressed as an open interval, but how do you express that union as a single open interval?  If it helps, feel free to draw a picture of the real line $\Bbb R$ and the intervals I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple examples of open sets, which are not balls, in every metric space are $\emptyset$ and the space itself, which are open.

Even if you consider those sets to be balls with radius $0$ or $\infty$, respectively, you can take the union of two or more open balls, which is not necessarily an open ball anymore (see [user46944](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/131740/user46944)'s answer for the one-dimensional case).

What you can actually show instead is that every open set in a metric space can be written as a union of open balls (see [this quesion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135740/the-union-of-open-balls)). In $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can furthermore show that a set is open if and only if it is a **countable** union of open balls (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299260/union-of-a-countable-collection-of-open-balls)).